# Convert UTC time to local time in Javascript, giving future date

Tags: javascript, angular, utc

I am getting **created_at timestamp from backend in UTC format**, which i need to render in browser. I am **using date pipe in Angular-7**. After reading few blogs and stackoverflow, i wrote this function below to get normal date format, which i can pass through date pipe in angular to format.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

- **Issue**: The output is in future date.
- **Input**: "22-12-2020 03:44:09 UTC"
- **Output**: "Fri Jan 22 2021 09:14:09 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

```js
getDateFromUTC(dateString: string) {
    const date = dateString
      .split(" ")[0]
      .split("-")
      .map((number) => parseInt(number));
    const hours = dateString
      .split(" ")[1]
      .split(":")
      .map((num) => parseInt(num));

    const convertedDate = new Date(
Date.UTC(date[2], date[1], date[0], hours[0], hours[1],hours[2])
    );
    return convertedDate;
}
getDateFromUTC("22-12-2020 03:44:09 UTC")
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: UTC dates are automatically converted to local time (a JS Date object) based on your browsers timezone. No conversion should be necessary.  Double check if the back-end is returning UTC correctly.

Comment: Ok. So i am formatting the date in a certain format in Angular using [date pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) as `created_at: {{ time | date:'medium' }}`. Using UTC value directly in the template is giving "invalid date" error.

Comment: UTC ends in a 'Z'.  It looks like your BE is not returning standard ISO UTC. Assuming the value is correct, then it should be: 2020-12-22T03:44:09.000Z

Comment: Got it. This was an error on the backend part. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Months in `date` object start from `0`. So your code should decrease month by `1`. [Refer here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth).

```
Date.UTC(date[2], date[1] - 1, date[0], hours[0], hours[1],hours[2])
```

```js
function getDateFromUTC(dateString) {
  const date = dateString
    .split(" ")[0]
    .split("-")
    .map((number) => parseInt(number));
  const hours = dateString
    .split(" ")[1]
    .split(":")
    .map((num) => parseInt(num));

  const convertedDate = new Date(
    Date.UTC(date[2], date[1] - 1, date[0], hours[0], hours[1], hours[2])
  );
  return convertedDate;
}
var localDate = getDateFromUTC('22-12-2020 03:44:09 UTC')
console.log(localDate.toString());
```

Althought, I am not sure why you have a date in string in first place.

Comment: Ah, a very silly one. It starts from 0. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Input date is not standard ISO 8601 date format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

So, you need to parse it first. Here is what I think you can get with the help of `moment.js`.

```js
function getDateFromUTC(dateString) {
  const parts = dateString.split(' ');
  parts.pop();
  dateString = parts.join(' ');
  const d = moment.tz(
    dateString,
    'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss',
    'UTC'
  ); 
  return d.toDate().toString();
}

console.log(getDateFromUTC('22-12-2020 03:44:09 UTC'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.31/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

It returns `Tue Dec 22 2020, 09:14:09 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Comment: Glad to see this new approach. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will automatically convert to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) format automatically. You shouldn't need to do any date conversion.

Your back-end does not appear to be returning the correct UTC format  according to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_.28UTC.29) standard (UTC Dates end in 'Z').

The correct format for UTC is

`[yyyy]-[MM]-[dd]T[HH]:[mm]:[ss].[sss]Z`

For example:

`2020-12-22T03:44:09.000Z`

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue **a month is added** I'm not sure why

```js
function getDateFromUTC(dateString) {
  //console.log(mydate);
  var medate = dateString;
  var day = dateString.substring(0, dateString.indexOf('-'));
  dateString = dateString.replace('-', '=')
  var month = dateString.substring(3, dateString.indexOf('-'))
  console.log(month)
  dateString = dateString.replace('-', '=')
  var year = dateString.substring(6, dateString.indexOf(' '))
  dateString = dateString.replace(' ', '=')
  var hour = dateString.substring(11, dateString.indexOf(':'))
  dateString = dateString.replace(':', '=')
  var minute = dateString.substring(14, dateString.indexOf(':'))
  dateString = dateString.replace(':', '=')
  var second = dateString.substring(17, dateString.indexOf(' '))
  medate = year+'-'+month+'-'+day+'T'+hour+':'+minute+':'+second;
  //let utcDate = new Date(year+month+day+'T'+hour+':'+minute+':'+second);
  let utcDate = new Date(medate)
  var mydate = new Date(Date.UTC(
    parseInt(year), 
    parseInt(month)-1, 
    parseInt(day), 
    parseInt(hour), 
    parseInt(minute), 
    parseInt(second),
    0
  ));
  //Apparently one month is added. I'm not sure why
  console.log(mydate)
  console.log(utcDate)
  
}
getDateFromUTC("22-12-2020 03:44:09 UTC");
```